# Split string into 2 columns (Bigquery)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to split ADDRESS LINE into two columns - address number and street.

I have tried the following:

```
Select 
REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(address_number, r"([0-9]+)"), 
REGEXP_EXTRACT(address_street, r"([a-zA-Z]+)")
From table;
```

and

```
Select 
substr(addressline1, 1, 4) as address_number,
substr(addressline1, 6, 30) as address_street,
From table;
```

However, none of them seem to be ideal because address line does not have strict structure.

It can be:

```
Adressline1
9666 Northridge Ct.
P.O. Box 8070
369 Peabody Road
83 Mountain View Blvd
3279 W 46th St
```

I would say to cut it into two parts - and split it after first space but did not find the right way.

Comment: Address parsing and normalization is complicated. I would recommend adding columns for your parsed data, normalizing your data in a program (there are any number of libraries to do this), and updating the table with the parsed data. This will do the parsing better, and make using the data faster and easier. Then do this normalization on future data imports. Also consider if you really need to parse the address.

Answer (score 0):

You Can try following code

```
with data as 
(select '9666 Northridge Ct.' as add1 Union all
select 'P.O. Box 8070' as add1 Union all
select '369 Peabody Road' as add1 Union all
select '83 Mountain View Blvd' as add1 Union all
select '3279 W 46th St' as add1 )
SELECT
  add1,
REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(add1, r'\d+') AS numbers,
REGEXP_REPLACE(add1, r'\d+', '') AS non_numbers
FROM data
```

output looks like :-
[image]